# usar c# (y .net en general) en linux??? (especialmente ubuntu)

Tags: c#, linux, .net, ubuntu, asp.net-core

soy usuario de ubuntu desde hace no mucho y me pase de windows a este, dado la comodidad que me esta generando el mismo, el tema es que yo aprendi a programar principalmente en c# para luego pasarme a python por la facilidad y comodidad del mismo lenguaje, pero
**¿puedo hacer programas de escritorio con c# en ubuntu?? (ademas de otras tecnologias de .net)**
tengo entendido que en general c# es de microsoft, pero esto me genera dudas a la hora de saber si con el mismo lenguaje puedo hacer aplicaciones de escritorio multiplataforma y de una forma que sea comoda que funcione tanto en ubuntu **20.04 en mi caso** y no me genere la necesidad de tener que ir emulando todo y meterme en el "y si aqui funciona pero en windows no??"

Comment: Con .Net Core podes hacer software para todas las plataformas. Sino podes usar Docker para correr tus lenguajes en otros sistemas operativos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes ejecutar una aplicación .NET en linux o macOS mediante
[mono](https://www.mono-project.com/)

> Mono es una plataforma patrocinada por Microsoft para permitir ejecutar aplicaciones .NET en otros SO

Answer (score 0):

Una mejor alternativa es usar Rider con IDE y los template de Avalonia (Tipo WPF) para el desarrollo de aplicaciones tipo escritorio.

Saludos